# Number '0' (zero) cannot be converted to double at backend

Tags: java, struts

I am sending an array of Numbers from flex frontend to backend through struts framework as

```
    var knobValues:Array=new Array();
        for(var i:int=0;i<parXmlList.length();i++)
        {
          knobValues[i]=parBox[i].knob.value;
        }

  calcEnergy.send(knobValues);
```

where as knob.value is of type Numbers

If the array contains a number '0' the following error occurred. The error is in setter method of corresponding action class. When Array doesn't contain '0' no error is coming...

```
Error setting value
Method "setKnobValues" failed for object com.tcs.infra.ecm.action.SaveScenarioAction@8f0064 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setKnobValues([Ljava.lang.String;)]
```

Setter method in action class...

```
public void setKnobValues(double[] knobValues) 
{
    this.knobValues = knobValues;
}
```

Comment: are you sure its `ZERO` (0) and not letter 'O'

Comment: I am sending Zero (0) only...

Answer (score 2):

Method `setKnobValues()` is expecting an argument of type `double[]` (array of `double`) and you are passing it an array of `String`, according to the error message.

Comment: I am sending array only...
Ok...If that is the case, its working fine if the array has values other than 0...

Comment: I missed the `[` in the arg list in the error message.  Still, you are passing a `String[]` when it's expecting a `double[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setKnobValues([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

It seems you have version in-compatibility.

`.class` you have in compile time is different from the one you have in runtime (assuming this code is compiled fine).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I somehow managed to do this... 
It seems there is problem in understanding 0 as Zero, It is getting converted to String in between before coming to Action class...

So instead of sending values as []double, I send as a comma(,) separated string and tokenised that in the back-end...

Thanks for your responces :)